# Understanding function calling to object literal option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was just going through the source code of **[hierarchical-display.js](https://github.com/zavoloklom/material-design-hierarchical-display/)** plugin and came across the following line of codes :

```
// PLUGIN DEFINITION
// =======================
function Plugin(settings) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('zmd.hierarchicalDisplay');
        var options = $.extend({}, HDisplay.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof settings === 'object' && settings);

        if (!data) {$this.data('zmd.hierarchicalDisplay', (data = new HDisplay(this, options)));}
        if (typeof settings === 'string') {return data[settings]();}
        if (options.action in data) {return data[options.action]();}
    });
}
```

Quite a standard plugin definition , but what really is the below line of code

```
if (options.action in data) {return data[options.action]();}
```

doing ? Can somebody explain ? i mean i understand what it's doing , but i am just struggling to find a use case for that line of code , can somebody explain what and when would such a line of code come into play ?

The line of code can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/zavoloklom/material-design-hierarchical-display/blob/master/dist/jquery.zmd.hierarchical-display.js#L153)**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `data` object has property with name `options.action` which is supposed to be function then execute it.